# unique=True not working when the Modelform is passed a custom dictionary?

Tags: python, database, django, django-models, django-views

So right now I'm editting the Querydict that the modelform gives to the view to make the submission in one field all lowercase and have no spaces. but then when I construct and pass that dictionary back to the Modelform to be validated/saved it doesn't give me an error if the same thing has been entered more than once. It seems like unique=True should work for all submissions that are in the correct format not just ones from request.POST. Any help/insight on the issue would be awesome.

EDIT: CODE

THE VIEW THAT HANDLES THE MODELFORM

```
dict = {}
sitename = request.POST['sitename']
#insert an if statement telling them only letters are allowed
urltitle = ''.join(sitename.split()).lower()
dict['sitename'] = urltitle
make =  MakesiteForm(dict)
if make.is_valid():
      make.save()
```

MODEL IN QUESTION

```
class Makesite(models.Model):
    sitename = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique = True) 
    siteinfo = models.ManyToManyField(Siteinfo)
    ref_id = models.ManyToManyField(RefID)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' %(self.sitename)
```

Comment: @San4ez added the code hopefully that helps illustrate the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Don't reassign built-in `dict` function

2.Field processing logic should be done in clean method:

```
class MakesiteForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # your code... Then

    def clean_sitename(self):
        sitename = self.cleaned_data['sitename']
        return ''.join(sitename.split()).lower()
```

3.Show what errors you get if form is not valid?

Comment: Unique = True is still not giving me an error when then same value is entered twice